# Save the dependencies and only re-build the code in Docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm running a scraper on Cloud Run that runs with Chromium and Puppeteer.
For this I have to install the Chrome package and a lot of other packages in my Docker image.
But for every code change I do I have to re-build the image and it seems unnecessary to download Chrome, all the packages and dependencies again.

Is their any way to only re-build the code changes and not installing all the other stuff like Chrome?

**Docker file**

```
FROM node:12-slim

WORKDIR /Users/kod/Desktop/Code/Shopping-Feed/scraper-cloud-run

COPY package*.json ./

# Install manually all the missing libraries
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils

# Install Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: If you put all the packages/downloads into appropriate staging folders, I would think you could use a COPY to move them in rather than seeking them out from a network. But updating a codebase inside of an existing container would lose that if the container ever gets deleted.

Comment: Are you frequently changing your `package*.json` files? Otherwise I would expect Docker to cache all layers up until `COPY`.

Comment: Can you show us how you're building the image?

Comment: I don't think his package files are the real issue he's looking for help with. It's the packages he has to pull in using apt-get. Though with that in mind, I would think they would have layers available to add to your image instead of running installation to all of this.

Comment: To echo @DustinIngram, does it help if you move the line that `COPY package*.json` after the line that `RUN dpkg -i chrome`?  That would avoid reinstalling the OS-level packages if the Node dependencies or other metadata change.

Comment: This is how I build it ```gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/BLURRED/BLURRED```

Comment: @DavidMaze it did not work